# Не запускается код в cmd

Tags: java

Всем привет, в общем суть проблемы:

Есть пример программы из книги "Сьерра, Бейтс - Изучаем Java"

```
public class DooBee {
       public static void main (String[]args)  {
             int x = 1;
              while (x<3);  {
                   System.out.print("Doo");
                   System.out.print("Bee");
               x=x+1;
              }
              if (x==3)   {
                  System.out.print("Do");
               }
          }
     }
```

То же самое у меня написано в файле и необходимо запустить все это дело через cmd.

Я успешно компилировал этот пример командой: "javac DooBee.java" ; далее я это дело решил запустить: "java DooBee" ; и... ничего не происходит...

[image: Скрин CMD]

P.S. JAVA_HOME и PATH прописаны, другие примеры программ запускал через cmd и они работали соответственно.

Answer (score 4):

Точка с запятой - признак конца выражения. Её не должно быть между условием и телом цикла.

```
while (x < 3); {
    ...
}
```

Это цикл без тела и блок кода, который никогда не выполнится, так как цикл никогда не закончится.

Comment: Элементарная невнимательность, благодарю за пояснение, сразу же все заработало

Comment: @Nortien не забудьте принять ответ. Хотя, SergeyGornostaev, не лучше ли было ответ дать в комментариях, а вопрос закрыть? Это же обычная опечатка.

Comment: @AntonSorokin не был уверен, что смогу донести мысль в формате комментария. За закрытие я голос оставил.